# PointCloud vs. PointCloud2 for unstructured point clouds

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have an application that publishes an unstructured point cloud, which in turn will be used to update a costmap. I remember reading that PointCloud is going to be retired in future a versions in favor of PointCloud2.

However, a cursory look at PointCloud2 seems as though it needs well-defined height & width fields. How can I represent an unstructured point cloud using PointCloud2?

Can I simply set height to 1 and width to N, and expect the library to treat it as a simple vector of (x,y,z) co-ordinates?

K

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12046/pointcloud-vs.-pointcloud2-for-unstructured-point-clouds/) by [kbabu](https://answers.ros.org/users/453/kbabu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [PointCloud2 definition including comments](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html).
Your guess is right, you can set height to 1 and width to the number of points in your cloud.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3